# Listando dados do BD utilizando SELECT e ORDER BY

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, arraylist

**Dúvida**

Existe uma tela com um EditText e um Button. Ao digitar qualquer informação no EditText e selecionar o Button o sistema deve redirecionar a informação do EditText para uma activity e essa activity deverá selecionar no BD todos os dados que possuem essa determinada palavra em uma coluna da tabela.
Todos os dados devem retornar e serem listados em ordem de ID.
Nessa tela a qual os dados são apresentados será possível selecionar esses dados e ao selecioná-los deverá abrir uma nova activity para edição do mesmo.

**Classe para informação dos dados presentes no BD**

```
public class Atividade_Condicao {

public long id;
public String nome;
public String nome_processo;
public String responsavel;
public String departamento;
public String tipo;
public String detalhamento;
public String documento;
```

**Tela com o EditText e o Button**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView android:id="@+id/process"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="Nome do Processo:"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/etNome_processo"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btBuscar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:padding="15dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#1E90FF"
    android:textColor="#F8F8FF"
    android:text="Buscar" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btCancelar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:padding="15dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#1E90FF"
    android:textColor="#F8F8FF"
    android:text="Cancelar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Classe com o EditText**

```
public class BuscarAtividade_Condicao extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private RepositorioAtividade_Condicao repositorio;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    init();
    setContentView(R.layout.form_buscar_atividade_condicao);
    Button btBuscar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btBuscar);
    btBuscar.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button btCancelar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btCancelar);
    btCancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
            finish();// Fecha a tela
        }
    });

public void onClick(View view) {
    EditText nome_processo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNome_processo);

    // Recupera o nome do Processo
    String nomeProcesso = nome_processo.getText().toString();
    // Busca o Processo pelo nome
```

**Classe de Acesso ao Banco**

```
package com.example.alex.levprocess.banco;

import android.content.ContentValues;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class DataBaseAtividade extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME =    "/data/data/com.example.alex.levprocess/databases/lev";

// Labels table name
private static final String TABLE_LABELS = "atividade_condicao";

// Labels Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
private static final String KEY_NOME = "nome";
private static final String KEY_NOME_PROCESSO = "nome_processo";
private static final String KEY_RESPONSAVEL = "responsavel";
private static final String KEY_DEPARTAMENTO = "departamento";
private static final String KEY_TIPO = "tipo";
private static final String KEY_DETALHAMENTO = "detalhamento";
private static final String KEY_DOCUMENTO = "documento";

public DataBaseAtividade (Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // Category table create query
    String CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LABELS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NOME + " TEXT)" +       KEY_NOME_PROCESSO + " TEXT)" + KEY_RESPONSAVEL + " TEXT)" + KEY_DEPARTAMENTO + "     TEXT)" + KEY_TIPO + " TEXT)"
            + KEY_DETALHAMENTO + " TEXT)" + KEY_DOCUMENTO + " TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LABELS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * Inserting new lable into lables table
 * */
public void insertLabel(String label){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NOME, label);
    values.put(KEY_NOME_PROCESSO, label);
    values.put(KEY_RESPONSAVEL, label);
    values.put(KEY_DEPARTAMENTO, label);
    values.put(KEY_TIPO, label);
    values.put(KEY_DETALHAMENTO, label);
    values.put(KEY_DOCUMENTO, label);

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_LABELS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

/**
 * Getting all labels
 * returns list of labels
 * */
public List<String> getAllLabels(){
    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LABELS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // closing connection
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // returning lables
    return labels;
}
}
```

**Complemento**

Somente será necessário retornar em tela o nome e tipo das "atividade_condicao"

Comment: Em qual parte do código você está com dificuldade?

Comment: Não estou conseguindo criar a Activity para contemplar a situação acima.

Comment: Você ao menos já tem uma classe de acesso ao banco de dados?

Comment: Tenho sim, vou postar na pergunta a classe de acesso ao Banco.

Comment: Creio que o que você precisa é de um [**ListView**](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html). Veja se [este link](http://www.devmedia.com.br/android-criando-um-listview-customizado/26260) e [este aqui](https://androiddevbr.wordpress.com/2013/12/09/tudo-sobre-listview/), são exemplos bem simples de se fazer e de se entender. Qualquer duvida, basta perguntar aqui :)